# Ansible - modify xml with namespaces using community.windows.win_xml

Tags: xml, ansible

Is it possible to modify xml with namespace using community.windows.win_xml? For example is it possible to add new node under welcome-file-list in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

In docs is info "Namespace, processing-instruction, command and document node types cannot be modified with this module." but I'm not sure if I can't use namespaces or I can't only modify them.

I can add node under web-app node using

```
- name: Update web.xml
      community.windows.win_xml:
        path: "{{ webxml_path }}"
        xpath: /*
        fragment: "<new-node></new-node>"
```

but adding node under welcome-file-list doesn't work

```
- name: Update web.xml
      community.windows.win_xml:
        path: "{{ webxml_path }}"
        xpath: /web-app/welcome-file-list
        fragment: "<new-node></new-node>"
```

After deleting attribute xmlns from XML everything works.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to ignore namespace in xpath expression via:

```
/path/to/*[local-name() = 'somenode']
```

For example you can select all the values of `welcome-file` elements by using the following syntax:

```
xpath: "//*[local-name() = 'welcome-file' and namespace-uri() = 'http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee']"
```

It seems that this is [a known issue](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/57171#issuecomment-497712467) in `community.windows.win_xml` ansible module.